# New F drive appearing out of nowhere?

Tags: hard-drive, windows-10

Just today, a new drive appeared out of nowhere: F

F is not USB, not disk and not the normal integrated drive(which is currently C and D).

When trying to open, it requests admin access. Upon granted access, it still denies with this error:

> You have to use the category Security to access this drive

Running a virus scan that lists the files while it runs, some files include microsoft and MSI boot files

What is this drive? Why did it suddenly appear now?

Image: The F drive + disk management.

[image]

Comment: Open your Disk Manager by `Win+R`, typing `diskmgmt.msc`, and press enter. Update your post with the screen shot.

Comment: Based on the screenshot, it is a bootloader partition. Others have reported it to get a driveletter as well, even though disk management does not show the assignment anymore. I suspiect a windows update temporarily does this but it doesn't get removed in explorer somehow. Reboot and you'll be fine.

Comment: This assessment makes it a duplicate of the other I mentioned here, as exactly the same happened there.

Comment: @Polarbear0106 Yes it does. It's the second from left partition.

Comment: The EFI system partition is a partition which is needed when you boot from UEFI firmware. It hold the bootloader. EFI is requires to support at least one partition format which just happens to be compatible with FAT32.  Your screenshots show on EFI system partition which just happens to be the size we see and which is reqognised by windows as FAT32... Add one and one....

Comment: @Hennes: In that case, wouldn't the drive letter & volume label be shown in Disk Management, above the "OK (EFI partition)" label?

Comment: If a drive letter were assigned by the partiion manager (and not yet removed after opening the explorer window) thenyes. It should also stick around after reboots. Temped to experiment with diskpart to see if you could mount it using the command line (non-permanently).

Answer (score 0):

you go to command prompt, you can search it in search bar at your bottom left of windows and run it as administrator.

type in **diskpart**. hit enter.

type in **list volume**. hit enter.

you must find what number of your drive F in the list. 
let's say it is on number 3

type in **select volume 3** and hit enter.

after that
type in **remove letter=F** and hit enter.

Microsoft livesupport helped me with this issue. And they said it safe to remove it.

Goodluck! Have a nice day! :)